# Dots appear before section names

Tags: formatting

I'm compiling my document with ICML styling - header below.  My section names show "." in front, e.g. ".Introduction".  What gives?

````
% Recommended, but optional, packages for figures and better typesetting:
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for professional tables

% hyperref makes hyperlinks in the resulting PDF.
% If your build breaks (sometimes temporarily if a hyperlink spans a page)
% please comment out the following usepackage line and replace
% \usepackage{icml2021} with \usepackage[nohyperref]{icml2021} above.
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Attempt to make hyperref and algorithmic work together better:
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

% Use the following line for the initial blind version submitted for review:
\usepackage{icml2021}

% If accepted, instead use the following line for the camera-ready submission:
%\usepackage[accepted]{icml2021}


% DO NOT CHANGE THIS

% THIS IS OUR "EXTRA" SECTION 
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[sup-]{supplementary-icml}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts

\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols - THIS MAY CAUSE PROBLEMS
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{multirow}               % for multi-row labels
\usepackage{subfig}                 % for laying out multi-panel figures and tables 
\usepackage{cancel}                 % for crossing out characters
\usepackage{amsmath}                % for splitting multi-line equations
\usepackage{placeins}               % for table and figure positioning
\usepackage{mathtools}          % for \vdotswithin{}
\usepackage{resizegather}   % for gathering multi-lines to one line
%package for graph layout
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}  

\usepackage{amsthm}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} %May be changed to 1 or 2 if section numbers are desired.```
````

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing the document class. The recommendation is to provide a complete document which shows the problem which is stripped of everything that is not required to show the problem. My guess is that the document class doesn't correctly handle `secnumdepth` of 0, but without that information, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the `secnumdepth` counter to `0`. This implies that all sectional units at level 0 or higher (counting downward: -1, -2) will be numbered, while lower-level units (level 1, 2, 3, ...) will remain unnumbered. In most cases (this included), `\section` is set at level 1, `\subsection` is set at level 2, etc. So, `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` removes the numbering from any sectional unit in your article. If you don't want a sectional unit to be unnumbered, use its starred alternative instead; that is, `\section*`, `\subsection*`, ...

Regardless, since [this is a submission for a journal/article](https://icml.cc/Conferences/2021/StyleAuthorInstructions), stick to the template without changing much of the internals.

Comment: Duh!  Didn't notice the elephant in the room!